# Transpose Pandas DataFrame and change the column headers to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following Pandas sub-dataframe

```
         col1  name1  name2
522      a     10     0.2
1021     b     72    -0.1
```

`col1` has no duplicate. I want to transpose the dataframe and change the column header to `col1` values. Ideally the output should look like

```
Variable  a     b
name1     10    72
name2     0.2  -0.1
```

it is easy to transpose the df and label the first column as Variable

```py
df.transpose().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Variable'})
```

the resulting DF will have indices of original DF as column headers (and they are not sorted and don't start from 1 in my data!). How can I change the rest of column names?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.set_index('col1').T
print (df)
col1      a     b
name1  10.0  72.0
name2   0.2  -0.1

df = df.set_index('col1').T.rename_axis('Variable').rename_axis(None, 1)
print (df)
             a     b
Variable            
name1     10.0  72.0
name2      0.2  -0.1
```

If need column from index:

```
df = df.set_index('col1').T.rename_axis('Variable').rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Variable     a     b
0    name1  10.0  72.0
1    name2   0.2  -0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to do the task with a combination of `melt` and `pivot`. The idea is to

```py
df = df.melt('col1').pivot(index='variable', columns='col1', values='value')
```

or `set_index` and `unstack` twice:

```py
df = df.set_index('col1').unstack().unstack()
```

If the `variable` column needs to be a column instead of an index, then use `reset_index()`:

```py
df.set_index('col1').unstack().unstack().reset_index(names='Variable').rename_axis(columns=None)
```

[image: res]