# Transpose Pandas dataframe and change column header

Tags: python, pandas

this question is a duplicate, in a sense I want exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139203/transpose-pandas-dataframe-and-change-the-column-headers-to-a-list).

So, basically I have following df:

```
Time | A | B|

1    |10 | 20|
2    |15 | 25|
```

I want:

```
Name | 1 | 2|

A    |10 | 15|
B    |20 | 25|
```

So, first I tried the accepted solution from the question: `df = df.set_index('Time').T.rename_axis('Name').rename_axis(None, 1)`, but it gives me `rename_axis() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. If I try only `df.set_index('Time').T.rename_axis('Name')`, the df becomes:

```
Time | 1 | 2|

Name
A    |10 | 15|
B    |20 | 25|
```

Even so if I print the name of first column with `df.columns[0]`, I get `1` and neither `Time` nor `Name`. I want the first column to be `Name`.

How can I transpose my df in such a way? Hopefully,the question is clear!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify `axis=1` instead `1` (I think function in last version was changed) and add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column:

```
df = df.set_index('Time').T.rename_axis('Name').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  Name   1   2
0    A  10  15
1    B  20  25
```

Or in last pandas version use parameters `index` and `columns`:

```
df = df.set_index('Time').T.rename_axis(index='Name', columns=None).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey, yes it works but it still says the name of the first column is 1. I want to be able to do df['Name’] of a sort.

Comment: @BlueMango - Added to solution.